# How to select multiple rows with MySQL while numbering the records?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have already asked a question like this, but never got a good answer so I'm giving another shot expalining it again.

Basically I have a table with 3 columns: id, user, number. I also have 10 records in this table, as the following:

```
        id      user    number 
        --      ----    ------

        1       user1   10
        2       user2   5
        3       user3   30
        4       user4   45
        5       user5   5
        6       user6   22
        7       user7   10
        8       user8   40
        9       user9   90
        10      user10  65
```

### Question 1:

How to number these rows and sort them by `number` and select a specific ID. For example, I want to select, id = `6`. It should sort the whole table and give a unique number to each one.

I need to get the following:

```
        SORT    id      user    number 
        ----    --      ----    ------

        1       2       user2   5 
        2       5       user5   5
        3       1       user1   10
        4       7       user7   10
        5       6       user6   22
        6       3       user3   30
        7       8       user8   40
        8       4       user4   45
        9       10      user10  65
        10      9       user9   90
```

I have found a function for it, which seems to be working:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT @sort:=@sort+1 AS sort, number, user, id FROM table, 
(SELECT @sort := 0) s ORDER BY number DESC) t WHERE id = 6
```

So this actually gives back a `sort` column of 5.

Is this correct?

### Question 2:

How is it possible to not just select the `sort` number of 5, but select 2 other columns as well. I need to select 2+ records above the sort number 5 and 2+ records below the number 5. In this case these record's sort number would be: 3,4 and 6,7.

I couldn't find a solution to select more rows.

Comment: your query states "where id = 6". However your deisred results contains all values for id. Something is broken. Anyway, the query you show is the common approach to get sequential result numbering.

Comment: question 2 is unclear: you say "select 2 other columns" and then give example of selecting 4 rows above and below sort=5

Comment: With question 1, I would expect the SQL to return ` 5       6       user6   22`. For your second question you would need to use your current sql as a sub query to return the row number, and then join that back against another similar query returning all the rows, but matching where the generated sequence number of with the range of the value from the first sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution to question 2.

Generate the sequence numbers once and get the row you want, then join that to the same query but where the sequence number is within the range you require:-

```
SELECT sub2.sort, sub2.number, sub2.user, sub2.id 
FROM
(
    SELECT @sort1:=@sort1+1 AS sort, number, user, id 
    FROM table, 
    (SELECT @sort1 := 0) s 
    ORDER BY number DESC
) sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT @sort2:=@sort2+1 AS sort, number, user, id 
    FROM table, 
    (SELECT @sort2 := 0) s 
    ORDER BY number DESC
) sub2
ON sub1.id = 6
AND sub2.sort BETWEEN (sub1.sort - 2) AND (sub1.sort + 2)
```

Comment: Thank you man, this is working as expected. Huh...it's quite an extensive query, yeah?

Comment: Its not too bad. Just remember to use 2 different variables for each of the sub queries. You would get some very strange results otherwise.